# Using values from a table in an SQL query

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Given three SQL tables,
`PEOPLE` with columns - `name` (varchar), `age` (integer)
`INFO` with columns - `email` (varchar), `phone` (varchar)
And a `master_table` as -

```
ID  |  TABLENAME     | RECORD  
--- | -------------- | ------------------------------------------------------------------  
1   |      PEOPLE    | "{"name": "Mary", "age": 12}"  
2   |      INFO      | "{"email": "xyz@abc.com", "phone": "321-456"}"
```

Now, I wish to write a query that loads data from the `master_table` into the respective tables. Something on the lines of-

```
INSERT INTO @TABLENAME VALUES @RECORD AS JSON 'AUTO'
```

Where, `@TABLENAME` is say, `SELECT TABLENAME FROM MASTER_TABLE WHERE ID=1`
and `@RECORD` is `SELECT RECORD FROM MASTER_TABLE WHERE ID=1`

How is it possible to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
insert into people (name, age)
select record::json ->> 'name', (record::json ->> 'age')::int
from master_table
where tablename = 'PEOPLE';

insert into info (email, phone)
select record::json ->> 'email', record::json ->> 'phone'
from master_table
where tablename = 'INFO';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However my use-case requires me to be abstracted to the data present in the master_table i.e. I do not know what table names may be present in the TABLENAME column, in which case in cannot use  
`where tablename = 'PEOPLE';` or  
`where tablename = 'INFO';`  
I somehow need to extract it from the table and use it in the query

Comment: And working under the assumption that these tables exist in the database with the JSON keys matching the column names

Comment: @C.Thullu: then you'll need dynamic SQL and a stored function. This can't be done with "static" SQL.